# Poner numeros en calculadora de android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo este código que abre la calculadora (por defecto) de Android. Lo que quiero hacer es poner números y cálculos, por ejemplo: Cuando se abre la aplicación, aparece: sin (180)

Asi como por ejemplo cuando abres un email y envias datos como:

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje);

pero no encuentro nada para numeros

```
public void ac(){
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {

    if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
        map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
        items.add(map);
    }
}

if(items.size()>=1){
    String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
    Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (i != null)
        startActivity(i);
}
else{
    // Application not found
    Toast.makeText(CMF_Home.this, "You don't have an calculator app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

}

Comment: el putExtra no te permite enviar números?

Comment: Deberia, ya intente esto: (intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 123) conny sin comillas los numeros